# Sometimes Image is not displaying for only one user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ashx

I am having ASP.NET MVC application in which i am using HTTP handler ashx file to get the image on the page . This image is uploaded by user by scanning the document.

Now my problem is for every user its displaying except one , User is reporting he is not able to see the image even though it was loaded sucessfully , when i checked the logs it shown that server got image. 
No exception was logged at the server while converting image too :(
One more thing this is happening frequently , 70% times user is not able to see the image in the page. 30% time he managed to see the image ... 
Strange issue 
Please advice what could be the issue ?

Below is my code

```
 public class GetImage : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{

    public GetImage()
    {

    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Params["side"]))
            {
                bool isFront = false;
                if (context.Request.Params["side"].Equals("Front"))
                {
                    isFront = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isFront = false;
                }


                ICache Cache = CacheManager.SessionCache;
                DepositState depState = (DepositState)Cache[Constants.DepositSession];

                if (depState != null)
                {
                    byte[] imageByteArray = null;
                    System.IO.MemoryStream imageMemoryStream = null;
                    try
                    {

                        if (isFront)
                        {
                            imageByteArray = System.Convert.FromBase64String(depState.FrontJpegBase64);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            imageByteArray = System.Convert.FromBase64String(depState.BackJpegBase64);
                        }

                        imageMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageByteArray);

                        using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageMemoryStream))
                        {
                            img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception  ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error(Constants.DefaultErrorCode, "Exception occured while converting image to Base 64 in GetImage.ashx.cs" + ex);

                    }

                    imageMemoryStream.Close();
                    context.Response.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Error(Constants.DefaultErrorCode, " Deposit State object is nullin GetImage.ashx ");

                }



            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Error(Constants.DefaultErrorCode, "Context is null in the Process Request  ");
        }


    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help without your seeing your code.

Comment: Nor without knowing other specific issues like that users browser and configuration, as well as the link to an image itself.
However, most of that probably isn't necessary.  Does that user see other images?  If you give them a direct link to the image what happens?  etc..

Comment: @jfar and Chris , i have updated the post as suggested

Comment: How many users are we talking about? Is it 1 user out of 4, or 1 out user out of 500. Becuase if you have alot of user's and they are running the site in similar environments and conditions then chances are there is a problem or configuration issue with the end user's computer not your code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you are setting the context.Response.ContentType.  I haven't tested this, but I wonder if the missing header would cause unpredictable browser behavior.